# For loop that can accept array and element query without throwing .all deprecation error

Tags: craft3

I have a component that accepts both hardcoded objects and entry queries. This allows us to have components that can be used independent of the database.

**Hardcode include:**

```
{% include '_components/callToAction' with {
    headline: 'Hardcode call to CTA Headline',
    body: 'Hardcode call to CTA',
    items: [
      { name: 'item1'},
      { name: 'item2'} 
    ]
} %}
```

**db include:**

```
{% include '_components/callToAction' with {
    entry: entry.callToAction
} %}
```

**Component:**

```
{% set component = {
  headline: headline ?? entry.headline ?? null,
  body: body ?? entry.body ?? null,
  items: items ?? entry.items ?? null
} %}

<h1>{{ component.headline }}</h1>
<p>{{ component.body }}</p>

{% for item in component.items %}
  {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Both those work fine, but with Craft 3 we're getting deprecation errors for not using `.all()` when it is an element query which is drastically increasing our db queries on the pages that use several of these components.

Comment: And why do you refuse to execute the query? Seems no difference to me. Of course it makes sense in certain scenarios, but not in yours

Comment: Not sure I understand, but `items` in the component won't work on the hardcoded include with .all() but it throws an error without it when it is run with the db include.

Comment: You can either check if the current instance of  `items` is an element of type ElementQuery or you pass the related items within it. `entry: entry.callToAction, items: entry.items.all()` or `items: items ?? entry.items.all() ?? null` I just want to understand why you don't want to execute it

Comment: @RobinSchambach - I do want to execute it, I updated my example code which I think is where the confusion is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to loop through an object (your Query) you could just execute it

```
{% set component = {
    headline: headline ?? entry.headline ?? null,
    body: body ?? entry.body ?? null,
    items: items ?? entry.items.all() ?? null
} %}

<h1>{{ component.headline }}</h1>
<p>{{ component.body }}</p>

{% for item in component.items %}
    {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

or if that doesn't fit your case, you can do it before

```
{% set relatedEntry = entry.callToAction.one() %}
{% include '_components/callToAction' with {
    entry: relatedEntry,
    items: relatedEntry.items.all()
} %}
```

You could as well check if your variable is an object of type `EntryQuery`

```
{% if className(entry) == 'craft\elements\db\EntryQuery' %}
    {% set entry = entry.one() %}
{% endif %}
```

Note: since you had multiple of these deprecated errors I wasn't exactly sure which one you wanted to "solve" and which one is "intended"